# Moving circle randomly disappears (javafx)

Tags: java, javafx

Assignment for uni - have to make a bouncing ball that is moved using a thread and you can change the speed using the up and down arrow keys.

What I have works fine apart from the ball randomly disappearing behind some invisible squares of some kind. It may be related to the speed label in the top left because when I remove the label, this doesn't happen anymore.

Gif of the problem:

[image]

Control class:

```
public class Task3Control extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stagePrimary) {

        //create the ball
        Task3Ball ball = new Task3Ball();

        //create a label to show to ball's current speed
        Label labelSpeed = new Label("Ball Speed: "+ball.getSpeed());

        //create the root pane and place the ball and label within it
        Pane paneRoot = new Pane();
        paneRoot.getChildren().addAll(labelSpeed, ball.circle);

        //create a thread to animate the ball and start it
        Thread t = new Thread(ball);
        t.start();

        //increase and decrease the speed of the ball when the up and down arrow keys are pressed
        //also update the label to reflect the new speed
        paneRoot.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                ball.increaseSpeed();
                labelSpeed.setText("Ball Speed: "+ball.getSpeed());
            } 
            else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                ball.decreaseSpeed();
                labelSpeed.setText("Ball Speed: "+ball.getSpeed());
            }
        });

        //Create a scene containing the root pane and place it in the primary stage
        //Set the title of the window to 'Bouncing Ball Animation'
        Scene scene = new Scene(paneRoot, 400, 300);
        stagePrimary.setTitle("Bouncing Ball Animation");
        stagePrimary.setScene(scene);
        stagePrimary.show();
        paneRoot.requestFocus();
    }
```

Ball class:

```
public class Task3Ball implements Runnable {

    private double radius = 20;
    private double x = radius*2, y = radius*2;
    private double dx = 1, dy = 1;
    private double speed = 3.0;
    public Circle circle = new Circle(radius,Color.GREEN);

    /** Returns the current speed of the ball.
     * @return (String) the speed as a string, formatted to two decimal places
     */
    public String getSpeed() {
        return String.format("%.2f", speed);
    }

    /** Increases the speed of the ball by 0.1 to a maximum of 5.
     */
    public void increaseSpeed() {
        speed += 0.1;
        if (speed > 5)
            speed = 5;
    }

    /** Decreases the speed of the ball by 0.1 to a minimum of 1.
     */
    public void decreaseSpeed() {
        speed -= 0.1;
        if (speed < 1)
            speed = 1;
    }

    /** Moves the ball based on its current speed and direction.
     * Reverses the direction of the ball when it collides with the edge of the window.
     * Updates the circle object to reflect its current position.
     */
    protected void moveBall() {

        if (x-radius <= 0 || x+radius >= 400)
            dx *= -1;

        if (y-radius <= 0 || y+radius >= 300)
            dy *= -1;

        x += dx*speed;
        y += dy*speed;
        circle.setCenterX(x);
        circle.setCenterY(y);
    }

    /** Uses a thread to move the ball every 20 milliseconds.
     */
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            try {
                moveBall();
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupt");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by improper updating of the `x` and `y` properties of the `Circle`.

Note that given your code the JVM doesn't need to guarantee that any modifications of the position of the `Circle` are visible to the rendering thread and that any modifications of the `speed` field are visible to the animation thread.

BTW: You do not mark the animation thread as daemon thread so it will prevent the JVM from shutting down.

**Setting thread as daemon:**

```
Thread t = new Thread(ball);
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

**Proper updating of the circle position**

```
// variable never updated so there are no issues with synchronisation
private final double radius = 20;

...

protected void moveBall() {
    // do updates on the JavaFX application thread
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        if (x - radius <= 0 || x + radius >= 400) {
            dx *= -1;
        }

        if (y - radius <= 0 || y + radius >= 300) {
            dy *= -1;
        }

        x += dx * speed;
        y += dy * speed;
        circle.setCenterX(x);
        circle.setCenterY(y);
    });
}
```

---

However using a `Timeline` for this purpose would be much simpler:

```
public class Task3Ball {

    private Timeline timeline;

    ...

    protected void moveBall() {
        if (x - radius <= 0 || x + radius >= 400) {
            dx *= -1;
        }

        if (y - radius <= 0 || y + radius >= 300) {
            dy *= -1;
        }

        x += dx * speed;
        y += dy * speed;
        circle.setCenterX(x);
        circle.setCenterY(y);
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        if (timeline == null) {
            // lazily create timeline
            timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), event -> moveBall()));
            timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        }

        // ensure the animation is playing
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

```
//Thread t = new Thread(ball);
//t.start();
ball.startAnimation();
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much Fabian! :)