# JavaFX Custom Nodes - force FX Thread

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making some custom nodes, like this:

```
public final class Indicator extends HBox {

    public Indicator() {
        Label label = new Label();
        indicatorText = label.textProperty();
        getChildren().add(label);
    }

    private final StringProperty indicatorText;

    public final String getIndicatorText() {
        return indicatorText.get();
    }

    public final void setIndicatorText(String val) {
        indicatorText.set(val);
    }

    public StringProperty indicatorText() {
        return indicatorText;
    }

}
```

The question is:

Is there any way to force the node usage on the Fx Application Thread? Should I check for Fx Thread in every method/constructor of the node? Or isn't this necessary?
I'm asking, because in some cases, like this -> [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358851/update-javafx-live-nodes-outside-application-thread)
JavaFX doesn't throw exception when the properties are being used outside the main Fx Thread and I really want to avoid it.

Comment: platform.isFXApplicationThread .. but why do you want it, really? It's perfectly valid to configure properties of a node off the fx thread as long as the node is not part of an active scenegraph

Comment: @kleopatra is there any way to figure out if node is part of the scene except getChildren().contains()? or shall i abandon the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what you do: check the currently running thread and throw an exception if it's not the FX thread.

However, this is possibly too restrictive: a lot of code on Node's can be run in other threads without issues.

In fact, **all** code in a Node can be run in other threads if the Node is not attached to the scene graph.

A better solution is to implement a catch-all for every thread that runs your code and deal with concurrent exceptions at the development / testing phase.